# How to print 10 number 10 times,9 number 9 times etc..Using Python

Tags: python-2.7

Output should be like this
10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8
7 7 7 7 7 7 7
.
.
.
1

Comment: Yes i dont want print 0 at the end...at the end 1 i have to print...Edited my query :)

Answer (score 0):

tyr it dear

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
d = []
for i in l:
     d.extend([i]*i)

print d[::-1]
```

Comment: Make sure you understand the solution as well. I suspect you don't, because I am not even a python programmer but I could have done this without too much thought... 

Have a look at whether or not you could remove the arrays as well - you shouldn't need to consume so much memory for this task...